# downloading zip files is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, zip, download

I am working on downloading zip files.I worked with the following example(link)
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/js/create-zip-file-javascript/
It works in fire fox and chrome but when it comes to safari the file downloaded as unknown .extension type.could anyone help in getting the .zip file in safari.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found any solution to this so far?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution but the workaround I see apple.com using is to ask iOS users if they would like to email themselves a link to the download page. You could just as easily show a message to all iOS users that says "If download does not work, please ensure you have installed dropbox (with a link) and try again."

---

Screenshot:

[image: How apple.com handles iOS users who click download iTunes button]